# How to create custom index for firestore query

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to be able to retrieve some data from my cloud firestore database where certain conditions are met and then order that data but I am unable to get my query to work. I've read that if you simply run the query then your log should provide you a link to automatically create the custom index but unfortunately within my flutter logs or the android studio logcat i'm not getting any links. I know you can create the custom indexes manually in the firebase console so i'm happy to do this but I dont know how I would create the index for this.

```
firestore.collection('users').where('organisation_id', isEqualTo: _authenticatedUser.organisationId)
.orderBy('first_name').getDocuments()
```

I just need to know how to create the composite index for this query so that it will work in my app

Comment: So you're saying the query fails, but you don't have an error message for that failure?  Have you tried capturing the error yourself?

Comment: @DougStevenson that's did the trick, silly of me to not think that earlier! Thanks

Comment: Would you like to answer your own question with your error handling code, so that someone else with the same question will have an idea what to try?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get a link in my console log by surrounding the firestore query with a try catch and printing out the platform exception which generated the direct link, thanks to Dougs answer

```
try {
        snapshot = await firestore.collection('users').where(
            'organisation_id', isEqualTo: _authenticatedUser.organisationId)
            .orderBy('first_name').getDocuments();

      } catch(e){
        print(e);
      }
```

Comment: I'ms trill not getting the link. I've tried to catch the error.